# InputStreamResource making heap memory full and killing K8 container

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, heap-memory, inputstream

From backend we are getting inputstream as String (this part we don't have control). Now we are using below code to convert that and return as InputStream.

We are using SpringBoot application. It's working fine but ***heap memory*** keeps getting increased and once it reaches at peak then containers gets unstable and restarted (and finally killed). During that phase API return 504 errors.
Current container memory is 4 GB and heap size is 600 MB. Our observation says heap memory is not getting freed by GC (even after hours) which is causing problem.

```
InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoder.decode(INPUT_STREAM_AS_STRING)));
                return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, ATTACHMENT_FILENAME +item.getName())
                        .body(inputStreamResource);
```

[image]
Anything we are missing above. What is best approach to make sure memory is getting used properly and there is no leak.

Comment: Have you taken a heap dump and looked at it?

Comment: It is ultimately the `ByteArrayInputStream` and the INPUT_STREAM_AS_STRING` that are doing that, not the `InputStreamResource`. Can't you transform the original input stream on the fly? instead of reading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 1] analyzing heap dump is next in the plan 2] We are getting INPUT_STREAM_AS_STRING from other API which is not in our control. So there is no original  input stream to try with  (its encoded String representation of actual Input String only).